# jQuery slide up/down on hover

Tags: jquery

I need to do, div "change" wait for the end, slidedown the div "username" and started slideup and same on out hover

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/2jHBQ/3/

```
 <div id="avatar">
        <div id="username">Madona</div>
        <div id="change">Change profile</div>
    </div>

$("#avatar").hover(function () {

    $("#username").slideToggle(250);
     $("#change").slideToggle(250);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the callback of the [**slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and if you want it on the way out as well you need to specify the handlerOut function of the [**hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method as well, only in reverse order, similar to this:

```
$("#avatar").hover(function () {
    $("#username").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#change").slideToggle(250);
    });
}, function () {
    $("#change").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#username").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/) - Slide one after the other - both ways

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the indented course of events is:

- `#avatar` is hovered

  1. `#username` slides down and hides
  2. `#change` shows and slides up
- `#avatar` is unhovered

  1. `#change` slides down and hides
  2. `#username` shows and slides up

In this case, you need two different handlers (one for mouse enter and one for mouse leave), since the order is reversed.

```
$("#avatar").hover(function () {
    $("#username").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#change").slideToggle(250);
    });
}, function () {
    $("#change").slideToggle(250, function () {
        $("#username").slideToggle(250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want. try this?

```
    $("#avatar").hover(function () {
$("#username").slideToggle(250,function () {
        $("#change").slideToggle(250);
    });  

});
```

or you could use `.mouseenter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .delay() method. It works quite well here as you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jHBQ/4/

```
$("#avatar").hover(function () {

    $("#username").slideToggle(250);
     $("#change").delay(250).slideToggle(250);
});
```

You can ready the API here:
http://api.jquery.com/delay/